# Lower function in python

Tags: python, string, lowercase

**I want to make my own lower function in python**

Just like we use:

**>>"Hello, World!".lower()**

**>>hello, world!**

***I want to make my own lower function***

I tried this code:

```
String = "Hello, World!"

def lowerFunction(MyStr):
    if "A" in MyStr:
        MyStr = MyStr.replace("A",'a')
    if "B" in MyStr:
        MyStr = MyStr.replace("B",'b')
    if "C" in MyStr:
        MyStr = MyStr.replace("C",'c')
    if "D" in MyStr:
        MyStr = MyStr.replace("D",'d')
    if "E" in MyStr:
        MyStr = MyStr.replace("E",'e')
    if "F" in MyStr:
        MyStr = MyStr.replace("F",'f')
    if "G" in MyStr:
        MyStr = MyStr.replace("G",'g')
    if "H" in MyStr:
        MyStr = MyStr.replace("H",'h')
    if "I" in MyStr:
        MyStr = MyStr.replace("I",'i')
    if "J" in MyStr:
        MyStr = MyStr.replace("J",'j')
    if "K" in MyStr:
        MyStr = MyStr.replace("K",'k')
    if "L" in MyStr:
        MyStr = MyStr.replace("L",'l')
    if "M" in MyStr:
        MyStr = MyStr.replace("M",'m')
    if "N" in MyStr:
        MyStr = MyStr.replace("N",'n')
    if "O" in MyStr:
        MyStr = MyStr.replace("O",'o')
    if "P" in MyStr:
        MyStr = MyStr.replace("P",'p')
    if "Q" in MyStr:
        MyStr = MyStr.replace("Q",'q')
    if "R" in MyStr:
        MyStr = MyStr.replace("R",'r')
    if "S" in MyStr:
        MyStr = MyStr.replace("S",'s')
    if "T" in MyStr:
        MyStr = MyStr.replace("T",'t')
    if "U" in MyStr:
        MyStr = MyStr.replace("U",'u')
    if "V" in MyStr:
        MyStr = MyStr.replace("V",'v')
    if "W" in MyStr:
        MyStr = MyStr.replace("W",'w')
    if "X" in MyStr:
        MyStr = MyStr.replace("X",'x')
    if "Y" in MyStr:
        MyStr = MyStr.replace("Y",'y')
    if "Z" in MyStr:
        MyStr = MyStr.replace("Z",'z')
    return MyStr


print(lowerFunction(String))
```

**But this code is too big, can we do this with a different technique?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: As a tiny optimization, you can drop the `if`s

Comment: what do you mean by drop the `if`s

Comment: `replace` replaces all occurrences – it simple does nothing when there are none. You can therefore do the `replace`s without checking with the `if` in advance. Simply dropping the lines and unindenting the remaining shall work.

Comment: Like this `MyStr.replace('A','a')`??

Comment: you can do `MyStr = MyStr.replace("A",'a').replace("B",'b').replace("C",'c')` ,etc. OR there is function `translate()`

Comment: Hint: The ASCII code for lowercase and uppercase letters differs by exactly 32 (or 0x20).

Comment: Please clarify what you would still consider "my own lower function". Is it fine to just make a single call/expression do the work, e.g. via ``translate`` or ``ord``/``chr`` roundtrip? Those would *functionally* be equivalent to calling ``.lower``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are too many challenges in your code.

1. Doing multiple replace statement. For each of those steps, python internally creates a new string. In Python, strings are immutable.
2. Too many if conditions.

```py
def _lowerFunction(char):
    if 65 <= ord(char) <= 90:
        return chr(ord(char) + 32)
    return char


def lowerFunction(myStr):
    return ''.join([_lowerFunction(char) for char in myStr])
```

Use `ord` and `chr` to check if its is Upper Case or Lower Case charecter.

```
>>> ord('a') # ord example
97
>>> ord('A')
65
>>> chr(97) # chr example
'a'
>>> chr(98)
'b'
```

Comment: This makes it easy!

Comment: This is a smart solution but it is important to note that it works for ASCII only.

Answer (score 4):

you can use ascii to replace characters.

```
stri = "Hello, World!"
lower_stri = ''.join([chr(ord(i)+32) if ord(i) >= 65 and ord(i) <= 90 else i for i in stri ])
```

This will check if the characters are among capital alphabets and replace them with small ones.

Comment: This is a smart solution but it is important to note that it works for ASCII only.

Answer (score 3):

Python has special function to translate chars - `str.translate()`

It needs `str.maketrans('ABC', 'abc')` to create lookup table.

But you don't have to write `ABC...Z` and `abc...z` manually because you have it in variables `string.ascii_uppercase`,  `string.ascii_lowercase`.

```
import string

def lower(text):
    lookup = str.maketrans(string.ascii_uppercase, string.ascii_lowercase)
    return text.translate(lookup)

text = lower("Hello, World!")

print(text)
```

Result

```
'hello, world!'
```

Of couse this works only for ASCII like other solutions.

For Unicode it would need all chars in `maketrans()`

---

**BTW:** using this you can cipher text with [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13)

```
import string

def rot13(text):
    lookup = str.maketrans('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
                           'NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm')
    return text.translate(lookup)

text = ro13("Hello, World!")
```

Result

```
'Uryyb, Jbeyq!'
```

Comment: Should that be calling like this: text = `rot13(.....)` instead?   Please correct it.

Answer (score 2):

This code may help you

```
def lowerFunction(MyStr):
    MyStr=list(MyStr)
    for i in range(len(MyStr)):
        v=ord(MyStr[i])
        if v>=65 and v<=90:
            MyStr[i]=chr(v+32)
    MyStr=''.join(MyStr)

    return MyStr

val=lowerFunction('Hello, World!')
print(val)
```

Answer (score 2):

One more solution using the list of lower and upper case letters. [The `maketrans` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65505411/813946) is faster, so you should use that, but this solution is closer to the original one.

```py
def lower_function(my_string):
    for lower, upper in zip(string.ascii_lowercase, string.ascii_uppercase):
        my_string = my_string.replace(upper, lower)
    return my_string
```

`zip` creates the lower-upper case pairs like that:

`list(zip('abc', 'ABC'))` is equal to `[('a', 'A'), ('b', 'B'), ('c', 'C')]`. Without `list`, it creates an iterator, that is fine for the for loop.

As the other solutions so far, it just works for ASCII characters, while the lower method works with others too. This will results in all lower letters:

```py
"CSÖN CSÖN gyűrŰ Arany GYŰRŰ".lower()  # gives "csön csön gyűrű arany gyűrű"
```

But you can use a longer list of characters in the `zip` part, like

```py
zip(string.ascii_lowercase + 'áéíóöőúüűä', string.ascii_uppercase + "ÁÉÍÓÖŐÚÜŰÄ")
```

But there can be some other problems, like the [German scharfes s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F#Capital_form).